# User-authorization on API-side with .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm writing a web-application in .net core that uses an API and a Website.

The web-service builds a JWT-token.
This is the service-configuration (removed unnecessary parts)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // The signing key must match!
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

        // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = "ExampleIssuer",

        // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "ExampleAudience",

        // Validate the token expiry
        ValidateLifetime = true,

        // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    };

    var serialiser = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>>();

    var dataProtector = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetDataProtector(new string[] {$"IronSphere.Web.Site-Auth"});

    services
        .AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        })
        .AddCookie(cookie =>
        {
            cookie.Cookie.Name = "access_token";
            cookie.TicketDataFormat = new JwtTokenValidator(
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256,
                tokenValidationParameters, serialiser, dataProtector);
        });

    //...
}
```

So far, so good. The login works, my website-side authorization works, I can work with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

The problem is now, I'm logged in on the website, but not on the API.

I can't use the `[Authorize]`-attribute for my API methods (and, yes, for sure, it makes sense).

So when I'm logged in, everytime I call the API, I also send the token in the header (this works, I can read it in the API-controller). I guess I'd need to deserialize it.

I tried with dependency injection to get that `IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>` into my controllers with:

```
services.AddSingleton<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>>(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>>());
```

then take the key from header, deserialize and I'd have my user-object with claims. But when I try to inject in any controller it makes my application crash (just a message, that dotnet stopped working)

Any idea how I can also validate the user when the api is getting called? (I could post more code if you need, just didn't want to fill here with too much code)

Comment: Just to be clear: client = your webapi, server = your auth/id server issuing the token?

Comment: @Tseng nope, not exactly. client is only the website, server is webapi (also handles auth-things and the token)

Comment: @Tseng just updated it. Was a bit misleading, sorry.

Comment: Okay so the client is an MVC application with views and cookie authentication, using webapi/auth server as openid provider? Since the client is not an webapi, you can't sign up with it with jwt (its typically passed as authorizaton request header).When you are successfully logged into the client, you can retrieve the token via `string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");` and pass that to the api you call, i.e. using `HttpClient` and `client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);` followed by `string content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/api/example/2");`

Comment: Also be careful calling `services.BuildServiceProvider()` multiple times it will create a new IoC container every single time and it shouldn't be called within ConfigureService. It will implicitly be called before `Configure` method is executed. Instantiate the type via new, it's okay since you're in  `ConfigureServices` which is the composition root. Also when setting the bearer token manually (w/ `SetBearerToken` method on  HttpClient, you have to add send its content as "Bearer <token here>", so the full header looks like: `Authorization: Bearer xyzabc`

Comment: @Tseng I guess everything works, untill the part with `i.e. using HttpClient and client.SetBearerToken(accessToken); followed by string content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/api/example/2");` .. mhh it's a bit difficult to explain. In my rest-client I'm doing this: `_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = AuthenticationHeaderValue;`

Comment: That's the point, for bearer token you have to add "Bearer " (with space) in front of the token, such as in `_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);` (Sorry updated the comment, didn't work directly with the headers for quite some time). But that should be the same as `httpClient.SetBearerToken(accessToken)`. The "Bearer" is the scheme of the Auth token (here Bearer token)

Comment: @Tseng I don't get it to work.. `GetTokenAsync` returns null. (I guess because the token is serialized!?). my cookie-value is not in the tokenformat (xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxx). I guess I still would have to deserialize it, or not?

Comment: @Tseng thank you for your input. helped me to fix this issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after @Tseng helped me a lot with his input, here is my result (more input on how to do it better would be nice):

1. Added the un-protector for the token as a service with adding in Startup.cs

   ```
   services.AddTransient<IJwtTokenService, JwtTokenService>();
   ```
2. the `IJwtTokenService`

   ```
   public interface IJwtTokenService
   {
       string UnprotectToken(string protectedText);
   }
   ```
3. the implemented `JwtTokenService`:

   ```
   public class JwtTokenService:IJwtTokenService
   {
       private readonly IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket> _ticketSerializer;
       private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;

       public JwtTokenService(IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket> serializer, IDataProtector protector)
       {
           _ticketSerializer = serializer;
           _dataProtector = protector;
       }

       public string UnprotectToken(string protectedText)
       {
           SecurityKey signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(" ......... "));

           TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters =
               _getTokenValidationParameters();

           JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
           AuthenticationTicket authTicket;
           string embeddedJwt;

           try
           {
               // logic to deserialize token
               // logic to validate token
               // more logic... (algorithm,..)
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               return null;
           }

           return embeddedJwt;
       }
   }
   ```
4. So in the services I also had to add the `IDataProtector`. It threw an exception before.

   ```
   services.AddTransient(x => x.GetDataProtector(new[] {$"auth"}));
   ```
5. Then I could add the `IJwtTokenService` into the constructor for dependency injection, unprotect it and sent it with the header:

   ```
   protected ServiceBase(
       IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, 
       IJwtTokenService jwtTokenService, 
       IMemoryCache memoryCache = null)
   {
       MemoryCache = memoryCache ?? new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
       CachingFunctionalty = new CachingFunctionality();
       HttpContextAccessor = contextAccessor;
       JwtTokenService = jwtTokenService;
   }

   protected RestClient CreateClient()
   {
       RestClient restClient = new RestClient(ServiceAdress);

       var token = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["access_token"];

       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token)) return restClient;

       var unprotected = JwtTokenService.UnprotectToken(token);
       restClient.AuthenticationHeaderValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", unprotected);

       return restClient;
   }
   ```

Now my API works together with the `AuthorizeAttribute`